# Conditional Expected Value with Min/Max

Tags: probability

Let's say I was given
$X\sim U[0,5]$ and $Y\sim\max[2,X]$

Then

$E[Y]=2\cdot P(X\leq2)+\int^5_2 x\cdot \frac{1}{5}dx$

My question is, why is it NOT

$E[Y]=2\cdot P(X\leq2)+\int^5_2 x\cdot \frac{1}{5}dx\cdot P(X\geq2)$

Comment: $Y \sim \max[2,X]$ Which distribution is that? or is $Y=\max(2,X)$?

Comment: @Daman I believe he means the maximum of  2 and $X$.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the formula you are thinking of is the law of total expectation:
$$E[Y] = E[Y|X\leq 2]P(X\leq 2) + E[Y|X > 2]P(X> 2)$$
Now obviously $E[Y|X\leq 2] = 2$. To calculate $E[Y | X>2]$, consider the conditional CDF
\begin{align*} P(Y \leq y| X > 2)&=P(X \leq y | X>2)\\
 &= \frac{P(2 < X \leq y)}{P(X>2)}
\end{align*}
for any $y \in (2,5)$. Differentiating the conditional CDF with respect to $y$ we get the conditional density
$$f_{Y|X>2}(y) = \frac{1}{P(X>2)}\frac{1}{5},$$
and thus we get
$$E[Y|X>2] = \frac{1}{P(X>2)}\int_2^5 \frac{y}{5} \: dy,$$
and inserting this in the formula, we see that $P(X>2)$ *"cancels out"* and we are left with the correct expression.

Comment: Thank you, this mostly makes sense, quick question: How did you get to the $f_x(x)\frac{1}{5}$ from the CDF $F_x(x)$?

Comment: This is by definition of the uniform distribution
$$X\sim U[0,5] \Rightarrow f_X(x) = \frac{1}{5} \: \text{ for } x \in (0,5).$$